# Visualforce Five9 CTI phone number linkable

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I am looking at making the phone numbers field from the contact object on a Visualforce page linkable with Five9. Currently the numbers are not showing as linkable to be dailed by Five9. Is there any apex or Visualforce script that I can implement to make this work?

Comment: Does Five9 use the phone number data type? Have you tried apex:outputField on a phone field?  How does Five9 enhance a standard page?  If javascript, you may be able to find the "hook" by examining the DOM.

Comment: Hi my phone number is showing in a apex:pageBlockTable column. I would like to know how Five9 enhances it pages. Let me have a look at the DOM and see if I can get anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of implementing click-to-dial is to send a GET request to the following address with parameters (number, campaignId, checkDnc):

```
http://127.0.0.1:9998/makeCall?number=9252012000&campaignId=0&checkDnc=true
```

It expects to be open in a new window, so for example, the code below uses an HTML link to open the link in a new window (target="blank"):

```
<a target="blank" href="http://127.0.0.1:9998/makeCall?number=9252012000&campaignId=0&checkDnc=true">9252012000</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>

function callFunction(telephone) {
    var newStr = telephone.replace(/[\s\-\(\)]/gi, ""); 
    var url = 'http://localhost:9998/makeCall?number=' + newStr + '&campaignId=0&checkDnc=true';
    $.get(url, function(data) {
    return;
    });
}
</script>
```

This solution does not open a new browser tab.